# Using React Context API alongside React Router - Issues with consumers re-rendering unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am playing with React's new Context api in v16.3. I am trying to set up my own Context within a React app that is also using React Router. I am seeing some strange behavior and am unclear as to what I'm witnessing and how to avoid it.

It's my understanding that with the new Context API, you can create a context that will give you access to a Provider and Consumer component. The Consumer component should take a render prop that executes whenever the Provider's value changes.

When I use a ContextProvider inside of a Router, this behavior works as expected. In this sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/lp5qj93l5z), MyContext.Consumer's render prop logs to the console every time it executes. It only logs out once, even as you change routes. This is what I would expect since MyContext.Provider's value isn't changing.

However, if I change my code structure and try to put MyContext.Provider around my Router, MyContext.Consumer's render prop function executes every time the route changes, even though the provider value is not changing. See the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/km2w2qlxl5

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Is this behavior expected, and why does it work this way?